# Zipping files together if they share the first part of their name

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, substring, 7zip

I have a ton of files in a folder that I'd like to zip together if they have a common beginning of their names (regardless of their extension).

Here is an example of 3 files:

"After the war (1989)(Dinamic)(Disk 1 of 2)(cr Replicants).st"

"After the war (1989)(Dinamic)(Disk 2 of 2)(cr Replicants).st"

"After the war (1989)(Dinamic)(cr Replicants).m3u"

I want to have them zipped together in a zip file that has the name of the m3u file.

I was trying to have a for loop that looks at every m3u, stop looking at the rest of the name after the 2nd closed parenthesis, then zip that m3u with any other file that has that same beginning part of their name in common (the part of the name until the 2nd closed parenthesis).

After reading other topics on the matter, here is the batch script I have so far:

```
For %%i in (*)*)*.m3u) do For /F "tokens=2delims=)" %%B in ("%%i") Do ("C:Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -mx9 a "%%~ni.zip" "%%i" "%%B*.*")
```

This makes a zip file with the proper name and puts the .m3u file in it, but not the other 2 files with the .st extension.

Could anyone please help me fix my syntax so the script works as intended?

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your original batch-script and it does not operate as your suggested. Perhaps you made some transcription errors when pasting it in!

Anyway, you specified what you needed, so I was able to work from that.

You seem to have made some common mistakes when building batch files:

- Don't try and get everything on one line
- Do develop the command in pieces

The first part is to test the outer loop:

```
for %%i in (*^(*^)^(*^)^(*^)*.m3u) do (
   echo %%i
)
```

It took me a few goes to  get the file pattern correct for `%%i` before proceeding.
The next stage is to build the inner loop:

```
for %%i in (*^(*^)^(*^)^(*^)*.m3u) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-3delims=)" %%B  in ("%%i") do (
      echo Zip: %%~~ni.zip Files: "%%B)%%C)*%%D).*"
   )
)
```

It also took a few tries to get the tokens correct and the patterns right. Then we can build the zip command:

```
for %%i in (*^(*^)^(*^)^(*^)*.m3u) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-3delims=)" %%B  in ("%%i") do (
       "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -mx9 a "%%~ni.zip" "%%B)%%C)*%%D).*"
       )
)
```

Is that what you wanted?

I get this when I run it:

```
C:\ ("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -mx9 a "Af
ter the war (1989)(Dinamic)(cr Replicants).zip" "After the war (1989)(Dinamic)*(
cr Replicants).*" )

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive After the war (1989)(Dinamic)(cr Replicants).zip

Compressing  After the war (1989)(Dinamic)(cr Replicants).m3u
Compressing  After the war (1989)(Dinamic)(Disk 1 of 2)(cr Replicants).st
Compressing  After the war (1989)(Dinamic)(Disk 2 of 2)(cr Replicants).st

Everything is Ok
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help in solving my issue! You also showed me how to develop the solution, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: At first, it did not work on some of the other files that had only 2 groups of parenthesis and not 3, but since I saw that this solution worked for files with 4 groups of parenthesis, I tweaked it to only require 2 groups and it works for 2+. I also added a * before the extension so it works on files with text after the last set of parenthesis. Here is the final batch script I used if others read this topic in the future for emulator purposes:

Comment: for %%i in (*^(*^)^(*^)*.m3u) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-2delims=)" %%B  in ("%%i") do (
       "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -mx9 a "%%~ni.zip" "%%B)%%C)*.*"
       )
)
pause

Comment: It would not be necessary to escape each round bracket in the wildcard pattern if the wildcard pattern would be enclosed in `"`, i.e. use `"*(*)(*)(*)*.m3u"` or `"*(*)(*)*.m3u"`.